# How can a submittable online form recognize ( \t ) & ( \n ) delimiters and skip <input>'s when using copy-paste from Excel?

Tags: forms, excel, input, copy-paste, delimiter

[[UPDATED AGAIN]] And I am sorry if this question gets wordy.

I am a hobby coder, and I am looking for some help with syntax and functionality within javaScript which will allow copied delimiters such as "\t" and "\n" to skip appropriate `<input>`'s in an online form.

I think I am about 33% there right now (again: hobby coder - self taught wanna be)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function splitInput()
{   
var x=document.forms["simpleForm02"]["dataInput_0"].value;
var delimiterT = x.split("\t");
var delimiterN = x.split("\n");

for (var i=0;i<delimiterT.length;i++)
if (x.indexOf("\t") >-1)
{
document.getElementById("dataInput_" + i ).value = (delimiterT[i]);
}

else
for (var i=0;i<delimiterN.length;i++)
if (x.indexOf("\n") >-1)
{
document.getElementById("dataInput_" + (i * 3) ).value = (delimiterN[i]);
}

}
</script>
<form name="simpleForm02">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Qty</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="colorInput" id="dataInput_0" name="colorInput_row_1" value="" onKeyUp="splitInput()"></td>
<td><input class="modelInput" id="dataInput_1"  name="modelInput_row_1" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
<td><input class="qtyInput" id="dataInput_2"  name="qtyInput_row_1" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="colorInput" id="dataInput_3" name="colorInput_row_2" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
<td><input class="modelInput" id="dataInput_4"  name="modelInput_row_2" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
<td><input class="qtyInput" id="dataInput_5"  name="qtyInput_row_2" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="colorInput" id="dataInput_6" name="colorInput_row_3" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
<td><input class="modelInput" id="dataInput_7"  name="modelInput_row_3" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
<td><input class="qtyInput" id="dataInput_8"  name="qtyInput_row_3" value="" onKeyUp=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This code kinda works, in a limited way. If I copy three excel cells aligned side by side, and paste it into `<input class="colorInput" id="dataInput_0" name="colorInput_row_1" value="" onKeyUp="splitInput()">`, then the script correctly splits and pastes the contents of the three cells across the top three inputs.

However, I obviously have flaws in the script because it doesn't recognize the '\n' delimiter at all. And I also know that I have coding issues with the circumstance: applying the code to all cells relatively, and not just `["dataInput_0"]`.

And lets presume I had the following data in an Excel sheet:

[image: Screen capture of a simple data set in Excel]

I am trying to find functionality that if I copied the Excel sample data above, it would overwrite/write the top 6 of the inputs in the sample `<form name="simpleForm">`.

Sorry to be long winded.

Comment: I suppose I could also consider and "onChange" javaScript command in the `<input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this question has been up for about a week, and during that time I have continued to look for ideas and help.

The solution which has presented to finest potential, but not a complete solution is via the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
         function splitInput() {
             var x = document.forms["simpleForm02"]["dataInput_0"].value;
             if (x.indexOf('\t') > 0) {
                 var delimiterT = x.split('\t');
                 for (var i = 0; i < delimiterT.length ; i++)
                    document.getElementById("dataInput_" + i).value = (delimiterT[i]);
             }
             else
                if (x.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
                     var delimiterN = x.split('\n');
                     var j = 0;
                     for (var i = 0; i < delimiterN.length ; i++) {document.getElementById("dataInput_" + j).value = (delimiterN[i]);
                         j += 4;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                     return false;
         }   
         function classFocused() {
            var d = document.getElementById("dataInput_0");
            d.className = d.className + " InFocus";
         }   
         function classBlured() {
            var d = document.getElementById("dataInput_0");
            d.className = "inputArea";
         }       
    </script>
    <form name="simpleForm02">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="0" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_0" name="colorInput_row_1" onFocus="classFocused();" onBlur="classBlured();" onKeyUp="splitInput();"></textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="1" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_1" name="modelInput_row_1" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="2" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_2" name="qtyInput_row_1" onkeyup="" ></textarea></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="3" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_3" name="costInput_row_1" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="4" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_4" name="colorInput_row_2" onkeyup="splitInput()" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="5" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_5" name="modelInput_row_2" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="6" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_6" name="qtyInput_row_2" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="7" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_7" name="costInput_row_2" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="8" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_8" name="colorInput_row_3" onkeyup="splitInput()" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="9" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_9" name="modelInput_row_3" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="10" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_10" name="qtyInput_row_3" onkeyup="" ></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea data-id="11" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_11" name="costInput_row_3" onkeyup="" ></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example of the textarea's, if a '\t' delimiter exists then the split is made and the data is spread over the course of the data's inherit length.

Also, in the above example of the text areas, if a '\n' delimiter exists then the split is made and the data is spread over the course of the data's inherit length vertically instead.  The statement: "j += 4" is in essence the number of columns you have in the form.

Though I still need for it to work across all text area inputs, not just the  identified as ["dataInput_0"]. A jQuery $(this) identifier maybe?

Also, the coding is limited because if you copy and paste cells which have both \t and \n, then the code doesn't work.

But it is a step in the right direction.